# GDB question: Pretty-Printing a 2D Array?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, xcode, gdb

I have a 2d array matrix[10][10] that I'd like to inspect at debug time.

I understand that I can do this in GDB using

```
p *matrix@10
```

But it outputs this in one line, making it difficult to read.

Is there a way to have this output formatted in any way, lets say as a matrix?

Comment: in C++ or objective C or C or what?

Comment: @Armen: In any of them, lets say I have an array int matrix[10][10].

Comment: `set print array on` will make gdb print pretty

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An important feature of GDB is the ability of execute functions in the debugged code, so you can implement whatever printing you like, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int matrix[10][10];

void print(int matrix[10][10]) {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
      printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main() {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
      matrix[i][j] = i*10 + j;
  }
}
```

After compiling this code with -g switch and running under GDB you can use the print function as follows:

```
(gdb) call print(matrix)
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

Answer (score 9):

You could always define a function in GDB to do the same thing. If you had the following c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 5

void printArray(int array[ARRAY_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE]) {
  int y;

  for (y = 0; y < ARRAY_SIZE; y++) {
    printf("[%d,%d,%d,%d,%d]\n",
        array[y][0],
        array[y][1],
        array[y][2],
        array[y][3],
        array[y][4]);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int matrix[ARRAY_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE] = {
    {1,2,3,4,5},
    {5,1,2,3,4},
    {4,5,1,2,3},
    {3,4,5,1,2},
    {2,3,4,5,1},
  };

  printArray(matrix);

  return 0;
}
```

You could then define the following GDB function (or something similar to it):

```
(gdb) define printMatrix
Type commands for definition of "printmatrix".
End with a line saying just "end".
>set $arr = $arg0
>set $y = 0
>while $y < 5
 >printf "[%d,%d,%d,%d,%d]\n",$arr[$y][0],$arr[$y][1],$arr[$y][2],$arr[$y][3],$arr[$y][4]
 >set $y = $y + 1
 >end
>end
```

which would result in the following output:

```
(gdb) printMatrix matrix
[1,2,3,4,5]
[5,1,2,3,4]
[4,5,1,2,3]
[3,4,5,1,2]
[2,3,4,5,1]
(gdb)
```

You could just as easily use nested while loops in your GDB function. And, as noted in a previous answer you can always just call the printArray function in your program from within GDB.

Answer (score 5):

Can you do this?:

```
p *((double (*)[3][3])pointerToMatrix3x3)

   (double [3][3]) $6 = {
  [0] = ([0] = 1821.8790830216928, [1] = 0, [2] = 1622.4513098457062)
  [1] = ([0] = 0, [1] = 1172.3930433142486, [2] = 1314.4812787191868)
  [2] = ([0] = 0, [1] = 0, [2] = 1)

p *((double (*)[4])pointerToVector4)

  (double [3]) $7 = ([0] = 1821.8790830216928, [1] = 0, [2] = 1622.4513098457062)
```

It works in lldb - Haven't tried it in gdb. It seems a lot easier.

Comment: This solution has the big advantage to be builtin. It does require to write a pretty-print function (in C or in GDB script). I checked it in GDB, and it works.

Answer (score 4):

This is a more helpful extension of the last post.
Also you can use: print var @cols@rows

```
define printMatrix
set $arr = $arg0
set $rows = $arg1
set $cols = $arg2
set $i = 0
printf "\n"
while $i < $rows
set $j = 0
while $j < $cols
printf "%8.4f,",$arr[$i*$cols + $j]
set $j = $j + 1
end
printf "\n"
set $i = $i + 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use try `p (float[n][m])Array` to print a 2d array in gdb.
For example, `p (float[3][3])*C`