# How Can I display A 2d array in gdb?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb, trace

I am trying to debug a program in c++ language with gdb debugger.

I have an array[100][100] and want just to see 5 elements of rows and columns and not more.

I can handle a 1d array with the following command :

```
display *arr@5
```

but how can I display a 2d array ?

I tried these but failed :

```
display *arr@5*5
display *arr@5 5
```

Comment: Try `display **arr@5@5`

Comment: yes it worked thanks simon kraemer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "double for" for a function to print it then calling it on GDB pretty much gets it done. Here I add a link to same kind of question. Good luck!

[Here an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4032290/5354875)

Answer (score 3):

You could create a function to print the information the way you want, say:

```
void print_matrix(int matrix[100][100], int number)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < number; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < number; ++j)
            std::cout <<  matrix[i][j] << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

And then call it on gdb:

```
call print_matrix(arr, 5)
```