# Better Pretty Printing of 2d arrays in VS Code Debugger - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

**Hi,**
I'm pretty to new to C++ programming on VS Code, so I have a couple of Questions to ask.
**My Software Specs:**

- Linux, 64 bit, Deepin 15.9
- VS Code 1.31.1
- G++ - 8, GDB 7.12
- Extension used : C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing by Microsoft

---

### C++ Pretty Printing of 2D array

I have to debug a lot of multi-dimensional arrays while programming and thus I want to know a method on how to view a 2D array, in the 'variables' window('watch' window will also do), in the form of a matrix.
Currently my variable's window looks like this[image]

I want it to resemble something like [image]

I know that a 2D array can be viewed using the method posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031957/gdb-question-pretty-printing-a-2d-array), but I want to view it inside the debug tab in VSCode. Is there any pretty printing method or code to help me accomplish my goal?

---

### Random Message On The Terminal When Stopping The Debug Process

There is some sort of message that appears on the terminal after stopping the debug process of C++. This is what it looks like - [image]

I switched from opening an external terminal for debugging to using the inbuilt one, since, after I stop the debug process, the above message is displayed and the terminal doesn't auto-exit, so I would have to close the terminal manually. This was not the case on windows, where the terminal would auto-exit after the debugging. Is there any way to prevent this message(It comes after the Debug finishes or is stopped)?

I want to use the external terminal for debugging, so is there a method to remove this error message, or auto-exit after debugging closes?

---

### These are my *.json files

**c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++-8",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "_runner": "terminal",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++-8",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

### Any help is truly Appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I guess your options are writing your own gdb [pretty printer](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing.html) or switching to lldb and the following extension which allows advanced visualization: https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb/wiki/Data-visualization